# Netty: Behaviour with 10 servers and 4 event loops

Tags: netty

Question: Consider one Netty client wants to connect to 10 Netty servers. All connect calls are async. Currently, we are using 4 event loops. Now, how netty framework will behave in this situation?

Answer: I have read netty book by Norman and according to my understanding. Since all connect calls are async and I/O happens on the event loops and the number of event loops are 4. The selector chooses among the connections that which connection it want to connect.But for a very brief period (the period between A and B where A is the time when the connection is ready to connect with server and B is the time when the selector picks that connection.) , I am not able to answer whether that connection stays in some queue or some buffer. If anyone can complete this missing piece, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you consider sharing the same EventLoop for all connections to the 10 servers?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your question but let me try to answer. If you will use 4 EventLoops and will establish 10 connections 2 EventLoops should have 2 connections on them and 2 should have 3 connections. This is as the default EventLoopGroup implementations use round-robin when choosing the next EventLoop to use.

Comment: As per your answer, Why the connections are different for the same number of event loops?
Also,  which event loop to use will be decided by selector right?